# Slide Show Presentation: Huge Margins

Tags: formatting, slideshows

When I create a standard presentation and enter presentation mode, left margins are huge, like 25% of the screen. Is there a way to reduce it?

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking. Mathematica has PresenterTools style sheets such as Sky and screen environments such as Scrolling Presentation, but no presentation mode. Pleas explain (by editing your question) what you mean by "standard presentation" and "presentation mode".